# Shall I add bypass capacitors on Clock inputs?

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, high-frequency, bypass

I am designing my first high-frequency (7-9 MHz) circuit for my undergrad thesis.

I am aware of the use and importance of bypass capacitors on the power inputs of my ICs and how (specially for HF) they will help.

However, one thing is not too clear on the datasheets of the components I will use is if I should add bypass capacitors on the clock inputs for my digital ICs.

I did add a .1uF bypass capacitor between the VCC input and GND on the oscillator itself, but one of my circuit boards will be using the same clock signal (I need it to be synced with the board where the oscillator is placed) and I am afraid that there will possibly be too much inductance through the cable carrying the clock signal? We are talking about a 166MHz clock.

Also, is running a clock signal through a 33ft long cable a bad idea? Is there a better way to synchronise two boards that are far apart?

Comment: At 166 MHz, 33 feet is [5.5 wavelengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line)...

Comment: At that kind of distance you should be treating this as an RF problem - try to get the source and load impedances matched to your cable.

Comment: Adding 0.1µF on a clock signal? Take a minute and think about what the impedance of that capacitor will be at said frequency (1/(2\*pi\*f\*C) ).

Comment: yes, you are right. At this frequency I should be thinking on the pF range shouldn't I?

Comment: Bypass capacitors provide a low impedance shortcut for high frequency signals to reach ground. Do you really mean bypass? You are thinking about shorting your clock signal to ground? This is a transmission line problem, you need impedance matching using resistive termination (probably).

Comment: user1850479, Thanks so much, you are right, I was asking the wrong question!

Comment: For 166 MHz over a 33 ft cable you should use a coaxial cable with cable impedance matched driver and receiver.